# Control cursor onload on tinymce/codemirror

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4, codemirror

I have a codemirror editor and tinymce editor side by side. When I load the page, cursor automatically comes at the tinymce editor. How can I prevent this?

**EDIT**

```
tinymce.init({
           selector: "#mytextarea",
           theme: "modern",
           plugins: ['ice code table contextmenu'],
           contextmenu: "align_element | add_callouts add_ref add_refitems",
           visual: false,
           toolbar1:'bold,italic,|,search,replace,code,|,ice_toggleshowchanges,iceacceptall,icerejectall,iceaccept,icereject,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,|,table'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you loading the `auto_focus` plugin?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#auto_focus

If you don't load that the editor does not grab focus on page load in my testing.

Comment: No. I am not loading `auto_focus` plugin. I have added my tinymce initialisation configuration for more clarity.

Comment: Perhaps its the `ice` plugin?  That is not a standard TinyMCE plugin.  If you remove it does that change things?

Comment: Correct! After removing ice plugin, the cursor is gone.. But I need that plugin. Is there any way to keep the plugin and remove the focus too?

Comment: Look through the code of the plugin and figure out why its grabbing the cursor?